# UWP Offset GridView Scrollbar

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, scrollbar

I am making a Gridview that scrolls behind a title element (which is semi transparent to show the items being scrolled behind it). To do this, I have layered the `Grid` containing the title and the `GridView` by placing them both as children in the same `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <GridView>
        <!-- Stuff -->
    <GridView>

    <Grid Height="100">
        <!-- Title Content here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This works fine, but causes the `GridView` to display elements initially behind the title. To fix this, I offset the `ItemsWrapGrid` in the `GridView`:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Name="ItemsWrapGrid"
                       Margin="0,100,0,0"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"></ItemsWrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Now the items start as if they are below the title content, and scroll underneath it.

The only remaining problem is the scrollbar for the `GridView`. The scrollbar still goes to the top of the parent `Grid`, which means it goes behind the title, even though the items in the `GridView` themselves begin below the title. This is particularly an issue when there are enough items in the `GridView` (rows) to cause the scrollbar to be small enough that it is entirely behind the title.

Is there a way to offset the scrollbar similar to the `GridView` items? Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Offset GridView Scrollbar

For your requirement, you could use `VisualTreeHelper` to get `VerticalScrollBar` element, then set `Margin = 0,100,0,0` in the GridView load event handler. For detail steps please refer the following code.

```
public static DependencyObject MyFindGridViewChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindGridViewChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}


private void TestGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollBar = MyFindGridViewChildByName(TestGridView, "VerticalScrollBar");

    scrollBar.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0));

}
```

Comment: I implemented this, and it works just as expected. Thank you!